# SQL SELECT everything except parameter

Tags: php, mysql

Let's say you have a query where you select something based on a paramater like this :

```
$parameters = [$country];
$query = 'SELECT g.* FROM game g ' .
            'INNER JOIN game_country gc ON g.id = gc.gameId ' .
            'INNER JOIN countries c ON c.id = gc.countryId ' .
            'WHERE c.name = ? ';
$stmt = $this->_db->query($query, $parameters);
```

So how this works is you select the countries that you want to be used.

My goals is to select the countries that will be excluded from the select.

So what I've tried is this in the WHERE clausule

```
'WHERE c.name <> ? ';
```

This works great as long as you select 1 country as soon as I select more it doesn't work. Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Any help is realy appreciated!

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

try with NOT IN :

```
'WHERE c.name NOT IN ( ? ) ';
```

And the params:

```
$stmt = $this->_db->query($query, implode(',',$parameters));
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer. I see what you're trying here but unfortunately it doesn't work.

Comment: The params be like an array no?

`$parameters = ['city1','city2','city3'];`

Comment: `implode(',',$parameters)` it will take `NOT IN ('test1, test2, test3')` instead of `NOT IN ('test1', 'test2', 'test3')`

Comment: But I don't have to implode when I just do `=` so why should I have to implode when I do an other operator?

Answer (score 1):

You try like like

```
// it is reset the index
$param_array = array_values($parameters);
$qMarks = str_repeat('?,', count($param_array) - 1) . '?';

$query = 'SELECT g.* FROM game g ' .
            'INNER JOIN game_country gc ON g.id = gc.gameId ' .
            'INNER JOIN countries c ON c.id = gc.countryId ' .
            'WHERE c.name NOT IN ($qMarks) ';
$stmt = $this->_db->query($query, $parameters);
```

**Note:** $parameters should be array.

Comment: This doesn't work unfotunately, thanks for your answer!

Comment: Can you share what you get for more details?

Comment: it says on the second line that the $qMarks variable is not being initiated and hasn't been used before

Comment: I don't face any error like that. Would you tried to initialize it and use of it.